# What is the maximum value for UID in an email inbox folder?

Tags: exchange-server, imap

I'm working on an application that uses the UID to fetch emails from exchange server. The UID appears to be only 6 digits long. Does that mean its maximum value is 999999? It's possible my inbox will reach over 1 million emails and I need a way to uniquely identify each email in the Inbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

By the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-8), it can be up to a 32-bit number, so 4,294,967,295:

> Unique Identifier (UID) Message Attribute:  A 32-bit value assigned to
> each message, which when used with the unique identifier validity
> value (see below) forms a 64-bit value that MUST NOT refer to any
> other message in the mailbox or any subsequent mailbox with the same
> name forever.

If you've had more than 4 billion emails in the past, the server will be forced to reindex, and change the `UIDVALIDITY`, invalidating any client caches.  If you currently have more than 4 billion, this cannot be strictly represented by an IMAP server.

Any given server implementation may have lower limits.  The numbers aren't zero padded, so it's likely you just haven't had a million messages yet.  When you do, you'll start seeing seven-digit UIDs.

Comment: It is a little unclear as to whether uid zero is valid.  I don't see anything forbidding it, but I think it's generally avoided.

Comment: It's forbidden by the [uniqueid rule on page 91 of the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-91).